# Memory-mapping a file in Windows with SHARE attribute (so file is not locked against deletion)

Tags: java, windows, mmap, bytebuffer, memory-mapped-files

**Is there any way to map a file's content into memory in Windows that does not hold a lock on the file (in particular, such that the file can be deleted while still mmap'd)?**

The Java NIO libraries mmap files in Windows in such a way that the mapped file cannot be deleted while there is any non garbage collected MappedByteBuffer reference left in the heap. The JDK team claim that this is a limitation of Windows, but only when files are mmap'd, not when they are opened as regular files:

https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2019-January/005698.html

(Obviously if a file is deleted while mmap'd, exactly what should happen to the mmap'd region is debatable in the world of Windows file semantics, though it's well-defined in Linux.)

For reference, the inability to delete files while they are memory mapped (or not yet garbage collected) creates a lot of problems in Java:

http://www.mapdb.org/blog/mmap_files_alloc_and_jvm_crash/

And there are security reasons why an unmap operation is not supported:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4724038

UPDATE: See also: [How to unmap an mmap'd file by replacing with a mapping to empty pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337460/how-to-unmap-an-mmapd-file-by-replacing-with-a-mapping-to-empty-pages/55981813#55981813)

Comment: @RbMm, we can delete a mapped file with a delete-on-close open (via `CreateFile` / `CloseHandle` or `NtDeleteFile`). In this case, the file system only checks [`MmFlushImageSection(SectionObjectPointer, MmFlushForWrite)`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/create.c#L3572) instead of `MmFlushForDelete`. It's probably a mistake, originally, but by now it's standard.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, you correct. we can delete file this way, if section create without `SEC_IMAGE` attribute

Answer (score 2):

as noted [@eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) we can delete mapped file, if section(file mapping) was created without [`SEC_IMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) attribute in 2 ways:

- open file with [`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) flag - *The file is
  to be deleted immediately after all of its handles are closed, which
  includes the specified handle and any other open or duplicated
  handles.*  or we can use [`NtOpenFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntopenfile) or [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile)
  call with flag [`FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile).
- by call [`ZwDeleteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566435(v=vs.85).aspx). really [internal](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/misc.c#L291) `NtDeleteFile` open
  file with `FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag and special internal
  disposition [`DeleteOnly = TRUE`](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/misc.c#L339). this is make call more
  efficient compare normal open file and then close it handle.

in code this look like.

```
#ifndef FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS
#define FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS 0x00000007
#endif

NTSTATUS Delete1(PCWSTR FileName)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(FileName, DELETE, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, 0);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return RtlGetLastNtStatus();
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}

NTSTATUS Delete2(PCWSTR FileName)
{
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;

    if (RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U(FileName, &ObjectName, 0, 0))
    {
        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName };

        NTSTATUS status = ZwDeleteFile(&oa);

        RtlFreeUnicodeString(&ObjectName);

        return status;
    }

    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}
```

note that call [`DeleteFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilew) fail here with status - `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE`. i recomendate call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` here instead [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) because win32 mapping `NTSTATUS` to error code is not injective and frequently lost valuable information. say `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE` mapped to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. but exist huge another `NTSATUS` codes which also mapped to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` not only `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` (real access denied). got `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE` much more informative here compare `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. the `RtlGetLastNtStatus` have exactly same signature as `GetLastError` and exported from ntdll.dll ( so include *ntdll.lib* or *ntdllp.lib*)

```
extern "C" NTSYSCALLAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlGetLastNtStatus();
```

Comment: @eryksun, yes, if file handle still not closed

Comment: It's dubious to blindly return `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` from a `CreateFile` call. `CreateFile` may fail without setting the last NT status value. For example, if the path is too long, translation will fail with `STATUS_NAME_TOO_LONG`, and in this case `CreateFile` simply calls `RtlSetLastWin32Error(ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)`. The status value is not saved in the TEB `LastStatusValue`.

Comment: In the second case I suggest using `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus` so we may possibly know why the call failed. This function is available in NT 5.2+ (Server 2003 SP1 and above), so it's not a problem unless you have to support ancient versions.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, agree about `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus`, simply it not exist on xp, but probably this already not problem

Comment: @eryksun about `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` yes, possible situation which you describe, but from another case `GetLastError()` really frequently lost information. how minimum for debug purpose exist sense call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()`. may be both this api

Comment: Yes, we may need both when coming from WinAPI, but we have to be careful about it, and leave it up to the caller. We can capture the `CreateFile` last status value as an out parameter and return the Windows error code. The caller can decide whether it's relevant. For example, the caller can ignore the status for `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`. It's mostly useful to clarify the reason for getting `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (a common and annoying example is `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY`).

Comment: @eryksun - this is because i personal prefer native api and for self code will be call `NtOpenFile`. no all such problems with error code

Comment: reverse mapping win32 errors (in dec format) to ntstatus(hex) - https://pastebin.com/A8t0FHCF in some situation (file api, virtual memory operations, etc), win32 error code can be very ambiguous

Comment: Thanks for the responses. To solve this issue in JDK on Windows though, files must be mapped without locking and *without knowing beforehand if the file will be deleted on close*. The reason is that the user may stop using the mapped file, even dropping references to it, but the garbage collector may not have run yet (which is how the file gets unmapped) when the user subsequently tries to delete the file. The file deletion will fail in this case. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: As another possibility, is there a way in the Windows API to atomically unmap a file, while keeping the original address space allocated but mapped to a Windows equivalent of /dev/zero (eg. so that reading from the mapped memory region returns all zeroes)? This would allow the JDK to add a close method that unmaps the file, while allowing the actual address space to be freed later by the garbage collector, solving the memory security issue that has prevented the JDK team from adding a close method.

Comment: @LukeHutchison - *The file deletion will fail in this case.* - which exactly status returned in this case by `Delete[1|2]` ? *atomically unmap a file, while keeping the original address space allocated* - no such api. this is exactly. you can unmap file, and then *try* allocate memory for this range. but this will be at first not atomic operation, at second exist posibility (real in heavy multithreads process) that another code already allocate patrially this range. about your problem with delete file fail - need more info for reproduce case. also in win 10 possible posix delete file semantic

Comment: @LukeHutchison - when you can delete file even while it in use (mapped). file instead full delete - unmapped from directory and not visible more. we can say create new file with such name. but file data finally will be deleted only after all use it end. [`FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information_ex) - but this require latest builds of win10