# How to unmap an mmap'd file by replacing with a mapping to empty pages

Tags: linux, memory-management, mmap, virtual-memory

Is there a way from Linux userspace to replace the pages of a mapped file (or mmap'd pages within a certain logical address range) with empty pages (mapped from `/dev/null`, or maybe a single empty page, mapped repeatedly over the top of the pages mapped from the file)?

For context, I want to find a fix for this JDK bug:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4724038

To summarize the bug: it is not currently possible to unmap files in Java until the JVM can garbage collect the `MappedByteBuffer` that wraps an mmap'd file, because forcibly unmapping the file could give rise to security issues due to race conditions (e.g. native code could still be trying to access the same address range that the file was mapped to, and the OS may have already mapped a new file into that same logical address range).

I'm looking to replace the mapped pages in the logical address range, and then unmap the file. Is there any way to accomplish this?

(Bonus points if you know a way of doing this in other operating systems too, particularly Windows and Mac OS X.)

Note that *this doesn't have to be an atomic operation*. The main goal is to separate the unmapping of the memory (or the replacing of the mapped file contents with zero-on-read pages) from the closing of the file, since that will solve a litany of issues on both Linux (which has a low limit on the number of file descriptors per process) and Windows (the fact you can't delete a file while it is mapped).

UPDATE: see also: [Memory-mapping a file in Windows with SHARE attribute (so file is not locked against deletion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138684/memory-mapping-a-file-in-windows-with-share-attribute-so-file-is-not-locked-aga/)

Comment: The only way to write to multiple memory locations atomically is by using a mutex between all the threads that are using that memory. If the threads aren't following a protocol to mediate access to the memory, you're out of luck.

Comment: @Barmar: that's not the problematic race condition here, it is the race condition between unmapping the file, and threads ceasing to use the address space the file was mapped to. What I am suggesting is to insert an intermediate step of remapping all pages in the address space to a placeholder empty page (which wouldn't have to happen atomically) or to /dev/null or similar, then unmapping the file, so that closing the file and freeing the address space can be completed in two separate steps. This would solve the issues in the linked bug report.

Comment: The problem described in that JDK bug is because Java code doesn't have direct access to the memory mapping system calls, and `munmap` happens lazily when the GC notices that the object is released. If you're coding directly to Linux system calls, there's no race condition when you call `munmap()`.

Comment: Of course, you have to coordinate access to that mapped memory between all the threads using it. That's not a race condition, it's just a matter of application design. Why would you even want to unmap the file before all the threads are done with it? And if they're not done with it, replacing the mapping with empty pages is likely to cause them to get errors.

Comment: @Barmar, you are misunderstanding the problem. See the linked JDK bug report. This is about fixing the JDK API (which requires fixing a potential security vulnerability), not an application bug.

Comment: It seems like the solution is for the unmap operation to not actually unmap the file until all `MappedByteBuffer` objects that reference it to be GCed. Maybe there could be a reference counter in the mapped file object, and the finalizers of mapped byte buffer decrements it; when the counter reaches zero, the mapped file can be unmapped.

Comment: @Bamar you just described the status quo, and it's problematic for many reasons. You can't always wait for GC, eg. on Windows you can't delete a file until it is unmapped. There needs to be a close() method, which is what the JDK bug is all about.

Comment: Well, if there were a way to do what you're asking about, I'd expect the JDK to use it, and the bug wouldn't be there.

Comment: Not sure I understand it fully however do the madvise MADV_DONTNEED, MADV_REMOVE, MADV_FREE options provide sufficient security until the gc calls unmap?

Comment: @danblack MADV_REMOVE looks like it is almost what I need -- but it talks about punching a hole in the backing store with FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE (and the fallocate(2) page says that "Within the specified range, partial filesystem blocks are zeroed, and whole filesystem blocks are removed from the file"). What would MADV_REMOVE do to a file that was simply mmap'd? I just want to unmap the pages and replace them with zero-fill-on-demand pages, I don't want to touch the underlying file.

Comment: haven't extensively played with these madvise calls, I just recall them from other uses of madvise. I'd suggest some basic unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you can use `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` to replace the mapping with any mapping you want. If you replace the entire mapping the reference to the file will be removed.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the bug remains in the JDK so long is fundamentally because of the race condition in between unmapping the memory and mapping the dummy memory, some other memory could end up mapped there (potentially by native code). I have been over the OS APIs and there exist no memory operations atomic at the syscall level that unmap a file and map something else to the same address. However there are solutions that block the whole process while swapping out the mapping from underneath it.

The unmap works correctly in finalize without a guard because the GC has proven the object is unreachable first, so there is no race.

Highly Linux specific solution:

1) vfork()

2) send parent a STOP signal

3) unmap the memory

4) map the zeros in its place

5) send parent a CONT signal

6) _exit (which unblocks parent thread)

In Linux, memory mapping changes propagate to the parent.

The code actually looks more like this (`vfork()` is bonkers man):

```
int unmap(void *addr, int length)
{
    int wstatus;
    pid_t child;
    pid_t parent;
    int thread_cancel_state;
    signal_set signal_set;
    signal_set old_signal_set;

    parent = getpid();
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, &thread_cancel_state);
    sigfillset(&signal_set);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &signal_set, &old_signal_set);
    if (0 == (child = vfork()) {
        int err = 0;
        kill(parent, SIGSTOP);
        if (-1 == munmap(addr, length))
            err = 1;
        else if ((void*)-1 == mmap(addr, length, PROT_NONE, MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
            err = 1;
        kill(parent, SIGCONT);
        _exit(err);
    }
    if (child > 0)
        waitpid(child, &wstatus, 0);
    else
        wstatus = 255;

    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &old_signal_set, &signal_set);
    pthread_setcancelstate(thread_cancel_state, &thread_cancel_state);
    return (wstatus & 255) != 0;
}
```

Under Windows you can do stop all threads but this one using `SuspendThread` which feels tailor made for this. However, enumerating threads is going to be hard because you're racing against `CreateThread`. You have to run the enumerate thread `ntdll.dll` APIs (you cannot use ToolHelp here trust me) and `SuspendThread` each one but your own, carefully only using VirtualAlloc to allocate memory because `SuspendThread` just broke all the heap allocation routines, and you're going to have to do all that in a loop until you find no more.

There's some writeup here that I don't quite feel like I can distill down accurately:

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?200588-How-to-enumerate-threads-in-currently-running-process

I did not find any solutions for Mac OSX.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but a nonblocking solution would be much better, especially since not all threads but the current one may be trying to access the file. That could kill performance for some workloads (especially in the Windows approach you suggested).

Comment: @LukeHutchison: I can prove the non-blocking solution doesn't exist.

Comment: That sounds completely plausible. However, this doesn't have to be an *atomic* operation, if it makes a difference. The main purpose here is to separate the unmapping of the memory (or the replacing of the mapped file contents with zero-on-read pages) from the closing of the file, since that will solve a litany of issues on both Linux (the lack of file descriptors) and Windows (the fact you can't delete a file while it is mapped).

Comment: See the new answer by Timothy Baldwin. That may achieve atomic remap on Linux at least.

Comment: PS there is probably a better (almost perfect) solution on Windows too, for uncoupling unmapping from file deletion, which uses `FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS` -- but that requires recent Win10 builds. See the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138684/memory-mapping-a-file-in-windows-with-share-attribute-so-file-is-not-locked-aga/